# Python strptime cannot understand timezone offset

Tags: python-3.x, strptime

I have a very simple timestamp I need to parse:

```
10/2/2020 3:19:42 PM (UTC-7)
```

But using python 3.6, when I try to parse this, I get the following:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('10/2/2020 3:19:42 PM (UTC-7)', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p (%Z%z)')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '10/2/2020 3:19:42 PM (UTC-7)' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p (%Z%z)'
```

I have tried `dateutil.parser`, as well as several variations of the format string. The piece that's tripping up `strptime` is the `(UTC-7)` portion.

Is the string format wrong? How can I parse this string and receive the timezone information as well? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: If the string is (UTC-0700) then the parsing works. But I cannot control how the timestamps are being formatted, is there a way to parse them in their current format (UTC-7)?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think strptime can parse that zone, you might have to parse it manually

Answer (score 0):

<s>Ah, it turned out to be quite silly:</s>

```
>>> import dateutil
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(dt, fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 2, 15, 19, 42, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 25200))
```

Should have used fuzzy logic before. :-)

EDIT: The above does NOT work (thanks to @wim for pointing it out) - Fuzzy flag is ignoring the sign of the offset string.

Here is code that works:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import re
>>> dt = '10/2/2020 3:19:42 PM (UTC-7)'
>>> sign, offset = re.search('\(UTC([+-])(\d+)\)', dt).groups()
>>> offset = f"0{offset}00" if len(offset) == 1 else f"{offset}00"
>>> dt = re.sub(r'\(UTC.\d+\)', f'(UTC{sign}{offset})', dt)
>>> datetime.strptime(dt, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p (%Z%z)')
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 2, 15, 19, 42, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200), 'UTC'))
```

Comment: Careful now.  Looks like this incorrectly parsed it to a +07:00 offset.  I think you wanted a  -07:00 offset.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! Any thoughts on how I can fix this without reverting to manual parsing?

Comment: Nope, as I commented on the question you may have to parse that manually.